# Json result undefined on client side asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get data in modal with ajax request for editing purposes. But json result on the client side is undefined. Can anyone tell me where is the problem in code and why I cannot get the result? I did not find the solution in other posts.
Here is a code:

JQuery:

```
$('table .edit').on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).parent().find('#id').val();
            var path = '@Url.Action("GetById", "BicycleTypes")'
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',                                      
                data: { id: id },
                dataType: 'json', 
                url: path,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#editModal #id').val(result.id);
                    $('#editModal #name').val(result.name);
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetById(int id)
{
    var result = _context.BicyclesTypes.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the status code and response returned by the request to your controller action? You can use the browser `Developer Tools -> Network tab` to inspect. Also, check the `Developer Tools->Console` tab for any javascript errors.

Comment: Hi Mohsin, Thank you for the question. Yes, I have tried inspecting in developer tools and status code is 200, and in the source I have a good path and id but the result is undefined. In the controller, when I debug, all seems ok